# Ansible unarchive exclude syntax

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to specify part of an archive not to extract via Ansible's unarchive module using the **exclude** option.

I believe the syntax should be roughly as shown here...

```yaml
 - name: Extract files from discovered zip file
   unarchive:
     src: "{{ base_path }}/weblogic-deployment/environments/{{ client_environment }}/discovered_domain.zip"
     dest: "{{ base_path }}/weblogic-deployment/environments/{{ client_environment }}/tmp"
     exclude: 
      - ./wlsdeploy/applications/
     remote_src: yes
```

I have tried a great many slight differences but the excluded directory is always output.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957188/unable-to-get-exclude-option-working-with-unarchive-module

Comment: I looked at that one, and tried the ./wlsdeploy/applications/ based on it but no luck (starting with period).  Thx

Comment: Have you tried `./wlsdeploy/applications` (i.e. without the trailing slash)

Answer (score 0):

The [`exclude` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/unarchive_module.html#parameter-exclude) is expected to be a list of paths to exclude. So most likely it doesn't support directories alone.

> List **the directory and file entries** that you would like to exclude from the unarchive action.

So try something like:

```
 exclude: 
  - ./wlsdeploy/applications/*
```

For some syntax examples, see: [`unarchive/tasks/main.yml`](https://github.com/abadger/ansible/blob/devel/test/integration/targets/unarchive/tasks/main.yml). Also check the [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/unarchive.py).

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the folder entirely:

```yaml
exclude:
  - "wlsdeploy/applications"
```

To extract the folder, but exclude the contents, you can use a glob:

```yaml
exclude:
  - "wlsdeploy/applications/*"
```

As the paths are relative to the archive, you don't need the preceding `./`.

If you need to look inside the archive first (to find the paths), you can use `less`:

```sh
less discovered_domain.zip
```

From the unarchive [tests for exclude](https://github.com/abadger/ansible/blob/devel/test/integration/targets/unarchive/tasks/test_exclude.yml):

```yaml
- name: Unpack archive file excluding regular and glob files.
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ remote_tmp_dir }}/unarchive-00.{{item}}"
    dest: "{{ remote_tmp_dir }}/exclude-{{item}}"
    remote_src: yes
    exclude:
      - "exclude/exclude-*.txt"
      - "other/exclude-1.ext"
  with_items:
    - zip
    - tar
```